# Why do my state update not impact another function currently running?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I am building a piece of code in which I need 2 nested components to update a state variable:

```
function Test() {
    const [test, setTest] = useState()

    async function wait() {
        await new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 1000))
        console.log("after 1s waiting, test is", test)
    }

    async function setTest1() {
        await wait()
        setTest("test1")
    }

    async function setTest2() {
        setTest("test2")
    }

    useEffect(() => console.log("after being updated, test is", test), [test]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={setTest1}>
                <span onClick={setTest2}>update test</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When clicking "update test", `setTest2` is called then `setTest1` is called. This happens asynchronously: `setTest1` might be called before `setTest2` ends.

First, `setTest2` and `setTest1` are called. Then `setTest2` updates `test`, giving it the value `"test2"`. At this point `setTest1` is still running. It is waiting 1s before continuing. After 1s, the value of `test` is undoubtedly `"test2"`. Is it not?...

When logging the value of `test` after waiting 1s, I would expect the result to be `"test2"`, since the state has already been updated to `"test2"`. However, the result is not `"test2"`, but `undefined`, as if it had not been updated by `setTest2`.

This piece of code logs this:

```
after being updated, test is undefined
after being updated, test is test2
after 1s waiting, test is undefined <--- what ???
after being updated, test is test1
```

It looks like some kind of scoping mechanism, but I am unable to find an explanation for it.

Why is `test`'s value not `test2` when logged in the `wait` call inside of the `setTest1` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "await" was added to call stack, before new version of "await" created.

- Step 1 : when you started your app, UseEffect ran first => "after being updated, test is undefined" ,
- Step 2 : When you clicked => setTest1 and setTest2 were called at same time. But "await" was declared at Step 1, and "test" inside of "await" was undefined, so after setTest2() finished => "after being updated, test is test2" , then setTest1() finished => "after 1s waiting, test is undefined" => "after being updated, test is test1"

**If you click again. The result is going to be:**

---- after being updated, test is test2.

---- after 1s waiting, test is test1.

---- after being updated, test is test1.

Because "await" is redeclared, and "test" inside of "wait" is "test1".

Hope this make you clear.
Some updates for more clear:

---

Everytime setState is called, new "test" is created with new value (not assign new value to current "test" ), but "await" still refers to old "test" ===> So this is why, you got "undefined" for first click.

Comment: but i don't understand how comes test is undefined after the 1s wait. after the 1s wait, setTest1 has finished and test has been updated to "test1". i would expect it to be "test1", not undefined.

Comment: setTest1 has finished after 1s, but setTest1 and setTest2 were called at same time => they were added to call stack at same time. setTest1 has finished and test = "test1". But  "test" inside of "await" still "undefined". because it was added to call stack before "test" updated to "test1". Before "test" updated to "test1" , it had "undifined".

Comment: You're saying that all variables used by a function are passed as copies to the function when it is called? that's not how regular javascript works, there must be a specific reason for this to happen. Is it a React specificity? Could you link me some piece of documentation which explains this behaviour so I can better understand it?

Comment: No, it's not pass a copy of variable to function, It just refers to the variable. But when you click button => setTest("test2") was called that cause to create new "test" with value "test2" => OK. but "await" still refers to old "test" with value "undefined".  ( After re-renders, you will get a new variable, in this case you will get new "test" after every setSate. SetState isn't mean you assign variable to new value, it will create new one ).

Comment: ok that's more clear to me, thanks for the explanation